# Reduce scrolling lag when using server side images for Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I currently have a tableView which can display any number of results. each row has an image which is pulled from a server. Assuming the Server is fast and the device has a reliable connection how can i reduce the lag when scrolling through the list.

I looked at loading the images on the background thread and this has definitely improved things however you can clearly see the images rendering as you scroll up and down.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil)
      {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }

      if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
      {
         cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      }
      else
      {
         cell.textLabel.text = self.TableData[indexPath.row];
      }
      _ImageURL = self.ImageData[indexPath.row];
      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
      dispatch_async(queue, ^
      {
          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_ImageURL]]];
          dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
          {

              [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
              [cell setNeedsLayout];
          });
      });
      return cell;
 }
```

Is there any method to improving this or is it more likely to be a constraint of the server speed and device bandwidth. My server is no Facebook server but its a decent paid one that i use for other applications.

Also since moving the images to the background task i notice that now and again a row will miss loading an image, any thoughts on this?

Comment: What you're doing is totally wrong. You must supply a placeholder and return immediately. Later you can reload the table when you have the image. Please do a search, as this is one of the most commonly asked of all questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use `SDWebImage` library, everything will be handled for you, from async downloads to caching management.
Here is  [the link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for downloading and documentation.

You can also use Facebook's  [AsyncDisplayKit](http://asyncdisplaykit.org/)  if you don't need image caching.

Good Luck.